# Datatable: Calculate age by using DateofBirth

Tags: jsf, el

By using DateofBirth attribute of an employee, I have to display it in primefaces Datatable.
I tried like this.

```
<p:column headerText="Age" style="text-align: center !important;">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{appointmentsBean.getAge('app.mtmdtreatment.dateOfBirth')}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
```

Bean.

```
     public int getAge(Date date) {

//code for getting today age.

    }
```

But there is an EL exception saying that cannot convert Date to String

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving a `String` (`'app.mtmdtreatment.dateOfBirth'` <- this is a String, watch the single quote) to the `getAge` method which accepts a `Date` parameter.

You have to give the `Date` object. This should probably work:

```
<h:outputText value="#{appointmentsBean.getAge(app.mtmdtreatment.dateOfBirth)}" />
```

Assuming you have a `app` object in context with a property `mtmdtreatment`.